# Why does `each do` cause a syntax error inside of an annotated method definition?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

This code:

```
private def not_ok
  collection.each do |x|
    puts x
  end
end
```

results in a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
```

**Update**: This was using MRI **Ruby 2.1.0**.  Apparently this behavior is version-specific and has been fixed in later versions, including 2.1.1 (!).  (Thanks to @Amadan and @JörgWMittag for pointing this out.)

Why does it raise a syntax error, and how do I get it to not give a syntax error without changing the `do` block to a `{}` block?

For comparison, these variations do not result in a syntax error:

```
def ok
  collection.each do |x|
    puts x
  end
end

private def ok
  collection.each { |x|
    puts x
  }
end

private def ok
  each do |x|
    puts x
  end
end
```

Since learning that `def` expressions return a symbol that can be passed to other methods, I've started individually annotating more of my methods with `private` instead of having separate `public` and `private` sections within the class (which I find less maintainable), and have run into this problem several times — any time the method contains a `do/end` block.

Comment: Cannot reproduce;  What is `collection`s class?

Comment: @JTG: I managed to reproduce it jRuby 1.7.11, and MRI 1.8.7; works in MRI 2.1.1, 2.2.0. Could be related to the change in `def` syntax? (However, not sure why braces would work, or the non-dotted variation...) OP, what is your Ruby version?

Comment: @JTG: `collection`'s class is completely and utterly irrelevant, since we are talking about a `SyntaxError` here.

Comment: @JTG, `collection` is just an array.  But like @JörgWMittag said, it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks for your comment.  I was using 2.1.0.  (I'm not sure why when I had newer versions installed.)  Glad to see this was fixed so soon, in 2.1.1.  Confirmed that this works in newer versions like 2.1.1 and 2.2.0.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Maybe instead of anonymously downvoting, you could instead please add a comment about how I could improve my question, or simply edit the question to improve it, as @sawa did (thanks, @sawa!).

Comment: It may not be perfect (sorry, I forgot to mention the version the first time), but I thought it was a good, honest, relevant question suitable for the Q&A format of StackOverflow.  It was tagged appropriately, included specific examples, ...

So why downvote it?? To discourage SO users like me from asking more questions? If the question is simply not relevant to you, why not simply refrain from upvoting, and move on?

Downvotes are an anti-feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that on older versions of Ruby, there is a precedence issue with `do`/`end` blocks.

You can get around that by assigning the return value of the `def` expression to a variable, and then passing that variable to the call to `Module#private`:

```
var = def not_ok
  collection.each do |x|
    puts x
  end
end

private var
```

Note, however, that on older versions of Ruby, the return value of a method definition expression is implementation-defined, so you have no idea what the above code will do. MRI, YARV, MacRuby, MagLev, JRuby, and IronRuby will return `nil` as the result of a `def` expression, which will `raise` a `TypeError`, since `Module#private` only takes `Symbol`s or `String`s. Rubinius will return a `CompiledMethod` object representing the compiled code for the method, but again, that will `raise` a `TypeError` from `Module#private`.

Only on recent versions of Ruby will a `def` expression evaluate to a `Symbol`, however, on those recent versions of Ruby, the precedence issue has been fixed as well, so that your code will just work.

It works on YARV 2.2.0 and JRuby-9.0.0.0-dev, but doesn't work on JRuby 1.7.18 and Rubinius 2.2.0 (that last one is probably a bug, since it claims to be compatible with Ruby 2.1.0).

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize this had been solved in newer versions (or that I was using an "older version", haha!).  I was using MRI 2.1.0 and it looks like it has been fixed in 2.1.1.

Comment: Good point about the return value being implementation-defined in "older versions" (apparently including 2.1.0).   It is surprising that something as important as the return value of a `def` expression would not be well-defined by the language.  I was going to ask if you could provide a link to the official definition of these semantics, but just found out to my surprise that http://rubyspec.org/ has been closed.  How sad!  How are Ruby implementations supposed to know which semantics are "correct" now?

Comment: See also: **Matz's Ruby Developers Don't Use RubySpec and It's Hurting Ruby** <http://rubini.us/2014/12/31/matz-s-ruby-developers-don-t-use-rubyspec/>.  "There is no definitive resource defining Ruby. Developers can only support multiple Ruby implementations with trial and error." <http://rubyspec.org/design/>